# How do I use my Lightsail WordPress blog with S3 Static Website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have a static website in S3 Bucket that I have distributed via CloudFront with SSL Certificate and used Route 53 to access it, my DNS provider is GoDaddy. Now I want a blogging website, for that, I have created an instance of Lightsail with WordPress Installed. I want to access that instance with a URL something like blog.xyz.com.

How do I achieve this? I assigned Static IP to Lightsail Instance and use Route 53 to access it via that IP, but the instance is not secured. I want to apply the same certification on it that I have created for my static website.

Comment: Do you wish to send users via your CloudFront distribution when accessing your blog, or do you want them to go directly to the Lightsail instance?

Comment: TY for the reply! I wish to send users via CloudFront with HTTPS with the certificate that I have created for my website.

Comment: I think you would simply create another origin in your CloudFront distribution that points to the Lightsail instance. Use a path like `/blog` to send `xyz.com/blog` traffic to the Lightsail instance.

Comment: I am going to try this, and see how it goes!